# SQLite syntax error near LIKE clause

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written the following `SQLite` query:

```
SELECT outlet_id FROM tbl_branch outlet_name LIKE 'U.K.G.H/W%'
```

but `logcat` says there is a syntax error near the `LIKE` clause. How do I fix this?

Comment: Add WHERE clause In your query

Comment: i added that,but someone removed it

Comment: @LahiruPrasanna Nope, see the [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22322526/1).

Comment: @LahiruPrasanna  Add Where clause it defiantly work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
"SELECT outlet_id FROM  tbl_branch WHERE outlet_name LIKE 'U.K.G.H/W%' "
```